# Is it guaranteed to safe passing [c++] POD types to [c] or vise versa?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Class or Struct compatiblity with C struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429440/c-class-or-struct-compatiblity-with-c-struct)

I read this FAQ: [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) , and got a following question. Is it guaranteed to safe passing POD types to C or vise versa?