# Using C++ struct with virtual members (i.e. non-POD) in C

Tags: c++, c, virtual-functions, memory-layout, vptr

In questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429440/c-class-or-struct-compatiblity-with-c-struct), compatibility between C++ classes/structs and C structs is explained as possible as long as all members are of the same type, in the same order, and no virtual members are declared.

That's my problem. I have virtual methods, and I would very much like to keep them when manipulating the struct in C++.

Let's examine this toy example. It's meant to be a C and C++ compatible struct defined in a single header file.

mystr.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>
struct mystr_base {
    virtual ~mystr_base() {}

    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct mystr
#ifdef __cplusplus
: public mystr_base
#endif
{
    const char* data;

#ifdef __cplusplus
    std::string toString() {
        return std::string(data);
    }
#endif
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This may not be exactly pretty, but will do for the example. In a real scenario, the C and C++ variants may be in separate headers, with the C++ struct extending a POD struct. Regardless of implementation, the issue of alignment is still present.

With this example, if a C program was written that passes an instance of `mystr` to a C++ function, the vtable will interfere with the alignment:

test.h:

```
#include "mystr.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void mycxxfunc(struct mystr str);
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

void mycxxfunc(mystr str) {
    printf("mystr: %s\n", str.data);
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char* testString = "abc123";
    struct mystr str;
    str.data = testString;
    mycxxfunc(str);
}

$ g++ -c test.cpp && gcc main.c test.o
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

(presuming that this is because the C++ function is attempting to read `data` from beyond the end of the struct's allocated memory)

What's the best way to enable this C-C++ interoperability while still retaining the ability to use virtual functions in C++?

Comment: Structs do not have any member functions in c.

Comment: @user0042 When compiled in C, there are no member functions defined. It is entirely valid to have a POD struct which includes member functions in C++, which will have exactly the same memory layout when used in C.

Comment: I'd advise at trying to commingle C and C++ in that fashion.  Keep them separate.  Have a C++ class that has-a member variable of the POD struct.  If you need to, pass a token (a void*) to the C side of the API for the C++ class instance, and package it (to a void*, or back to a C++ class pointer) at that C/C++ API barrier.

Comment: In general, polymorphic classes cannot be made compatible with C "equivalent" because C has no equivalent. You would need to know how these classes are compiled. Then your code would only work for the ABI of the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend you to clutter your header file with `#ifdefs`.

The first thing you should do in this case if you want to retain some kind of virtualization and C compatibility at the same time is:

1. Make your C++ and C type an opaque pointer to the representation.
2. Put implementation details in a .cpp file.

An idea follows.

Header file:

```
struct MyStrImpl;

struct MyStr {
   MyStrImpl * impl;
};

extern "C" MyReturnType myFunction(MyStr myStr);
```

Implementation in `.cpp` file:

```
struct MyCppString {
    virtual ...
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
struct MyStrImpl : public MyCppString {

};
#else
struct MyStrImpl {

};
#endif
MyStr::MyStr() : impl{new MyStrImpl{}} {

}
```

This way you have a type that can be used from both C and C++.

Advantages:

- No `#ifdef` in header file.
- Compatible with C/C++ and consumable from both languages.

Disadvantages:

- Lose overloading due to extern "C".
- Must use a C-style interface (but can implement with C++-like with virtual functions interface in your .cpp file.

You cannot have both a C-compatible type and virtual functions in a header file at the same time without cluttering it with `#ifdef`, something that I do not recommend since it can be inconvenient if you need to refactor code.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this answer as it makes usage clunky. For example, initialisation in C would be like `MyStrImpl* impl = (MyStrImpl*) malloc(sizeof(MyStrImpl)); MyStr str; str.impl = impl;`, and using methods in C++ will take the form `str.impl->toString()`. This might be fine for internal code, but it's just not acceptable for an API.

Comment: If you need something more fancy, anyway, the solution amounts to duplicate a C and a C++ implementation if you want different interfaces. You could add C functions for construct/destruct with current solution.

Comment: Sure, I could make a constructor function in C. This would have to assume that the caller is OK with using malloc (which may not always be the case). It's more about the ease-of-use. The user of the struct whether in C or C++ should never have to worry about implementation details, and just write code semantically. I'm wondering if user-defined packing will do what I want.

Comment: The fact that you hide the constructor behind a C interface does not mean malloc will be used. I get your idea about ease of use but that is going to complicate the implementation a lot. My recommendation here would be to split the C and C++ implementation in that case or you just have the option to clutter things with #ifdefs. You cannot guarantee a layout without an indirection AFAIK.

Comment: I peronsally prefer the hard way of doing things. If I can make it easy to use, with proper abstraction, I will. I can avoid lots of `#ifdefs` anyway by splitting the C and C++ headers.